# The compositum is also separable

Tags: galois-theory

> If $K$ and $K'$ are Galois extensions of the field $k$ then the compositum $KK'$ is also Galois over $k$

The normality is preserved but how to show the separability, what if one of the fields $K$ or $K'$ is only an arbitrary extension, not necessarily Galois

Comment: The hyphotesis says that both $ K $ and $ K'$ are Galois over $ k $.

Comment: @Charter so you say, if for any $f$ we have $(f,f')=1$ in $K[x]$ then also in $KK'[x]$ ?

Comment: I don't understand you, do you want a proof or a counterexample?

Comment: @Charter a proof

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'm gonna use the definion of galoisian extension to be a normal and separable extension. Now, by hyphotesis $ K$ and $ K'$ are galoisian over $ k $, so both fields are splitting fields of some polynomials $ p(x), q(x)\in k[x] $, respectively. If $a_{1}, \ldots, a_{n}$ and $b_{1}, \ldots, b_{m}$ are the roots of $ p $ and $ q$, resp., then $$KK'=K'(K)=K'(k(a_{1}, \ldots, a_{n}))=K'(a_{1},\ldots, a_{n})=k(b_{1}, \ldots, b_{m})(a_{1}, \ldots, a_{n})=k(b_{1}, \ldots, b_{m}, a_{1}, \ldots, a_{n}). $$ Therefore $ KK'$ is the splitting field of $ p(x)q(x)\in k[x]$, i.e., $ KK'/k $ is normal. Now, because $ K/k $ and $ K'/k $ are both separable we have that $ a_{i}, b_{j} $ are separable over $ k$. Thus, it follows that $ KK'/k $ is separable. Hence $ KK'$ is galoisian over $ k $.